# Process.clean option in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to figure out how to navigate to that option and test it out but I cannot find it in the Azure DevOps portal. I'm curious to see what it does with and without it on.

I've looked in the Azure DevOps section where the variables are as I suspect it's a system variable? Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't seem to be able to locate it there.

Comment: clean option in Azure DevOps pipelines is used to clean the local repository on the agent before the build starts. This option can be set to true or false and is used to ensure that the repository is in a clean state before the build starts. The clean option is set in the `Get sources task`, which is used to get the source code for the build. To set the clean option, go to the `Tasks` tab in the pipeline editor, select the Get sources task, and then select the Show `Advanced settings` option. The clean option is located under the `Repository` tab.

Comment: @Arko that's a different `clean` configuration.

Comment: There isn't such an option in the UI. The `Process.clean` variable is used to control whether the “finalize job” step in an Azure DevOps pipeline should terminate all processes or not. By default, this variable is set to `true` and it ensures that any running processes are forcefully terminated at the end of the pipeline run. If you set it to `false`, the “finalize job” step will not kill all processes, allowing them to continue running even after the pipeline execution completes as mentioned in the ticket shared by Shamrai.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of hidden environment variables that control certain behaviors of the Azure Pipelines Agent. Usually they are only used when you're trying to do something with the Agent it wasn't really designed for (like starting a background process on the agent that should survive the Job's lifetime).

When you define a pipeline variable, it automatically sets a matching environment variable for the duration of the job that references that variable.

It doesn't matter where that variable is defined, in the Variables section in the GUI, in a referenced Variable Library, in the YAML file or even at runtime in some cases through a workflow command. Some of these settings can even be controlled from the Service account user's or System's environment variables (for self-hosted agents).

It looks like the `process. Clean` option **must** be defined as a variable and cannot be set through the environment for some reason.

In this case, just set the variable anywhere and it will start to change the behavior of the job. Personally, [I'd put it in the YAML file, if possible only in the job section of the job needing this behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), as you'll be able to document the reason in there using comments.

```
jobs:
  build:
    variables:
      # turns off automatic process termination at the end of the job
      # we need this for special reason XYZ.
      - name: "process.clean"
        value: false
    steps:
      - ...
```

If you want to know more about these magic variables, [search the azure-pipelines-agent repository for `variable.get` and `knobs` and `GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fazure-pipelines-agent%20%28%22Variables.Get%22%20OR%20%22environmentvariable%22%20OR%20%22knob%22%29&type=code).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I will try right now and see what happens :) Kudos!